# Will calling base on an inherited method call return also?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say my base method looks like:

```
public int GetCount() {.....}
```

Now I inherit from GetCount's class, and do:

```
public new int GetCount()
{
  int count = base.GetCount();

  count += 1;


  return count;

}
```

Will calling base.GetCount() cause a return before my increment? (that seems to be what I am experiencing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it will not.  Calling base.Count is no different with respect to returning from the method than any other method call.

In a normal C# method (excluding iterators and abnormal process termination), there are only 3 ways to leave a method

- Explicit call to return
- Execution goes beyond the last instruction in a code path for a void returning method
- Thrown exception, in the function or a called one, reaches the current method and is unhandled

Answer (score 2):

No, why it should return? There's no return statement there. Make sure you are not mistakenly calling the base method. Probably showing us the code that calls it helps. If you are calling it like:

```
Base b = new Derived();
int result = b.GetCount();
```

you are calling the base method.

Answer (score 1):

Your base class method should be virtual, if not your sub-class method won't be called.

```
public virtual int GetCount() {.....}
```

Sub-class, `override` instead of `new`:

```
public override int GetCount()
{
  int count = base.GetCount();

  count += 1;


  return count;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the base method virtual (if possible), then override it instead.